# Why does subprocess return double "\" (ex. "1\\n2") when used in a shell script?

Tags: python, subprocess, escaping

If I do the following:

```
>>> cmd='echo -n "1\n2"'
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
>>> proc.stdout.read()
'1\n2'
```

but if I use a shell script:

```
cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo -n "1\n2"

>>> cmd='sh test.sh'
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
>>> proc.stdout.read()
'1\\n2'
```

and I change `\n` to `\t`

```
cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo -n "1\t2"

>>> cmd='sh test.sh'
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf-8')
>>> proc.stdout.read()
'1\\t2'
```

Why does using a script get two `\` ?

Comment: The shell script escape the string contents before using it

Comment: Can you please clarify what OS you are running this on? There are multiple shells involved, at least the one by ``shell=True`` and the one by ``sh test.sh``. On my system, the second blocks provides ``'-n 1\n2\n'`` instead – this is consistent with running ``sh -c 'echo -n "1\n2"'`` directly.

Comment: For my man page (BSD General Commands Manual): "Most notably, the **builtin echo in sh(1)** does not accept the -n option." For a [Linux echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo), you need "-e
enable interpretation of backslash escapes". It appears you are using the wrong shell for the given code.